# read-only FTP access on Fritzbox

Tags: internet, ftp, fritzbox

I am trying to access the contents of my hard drive which is connected to a FRITZ!box 7490. The FRITZ! box can be accessed by both SMB and FTP. Sometimes I need to access files from outside of the FRITZ network so I use FTP and access it over the internet with a subdomain from [afraid.org](https://afraid.org) My problem is that, even though I have set the webGUI to allow access for me to access the files, I still get a read-only error. See below:

[image: read only error]
[image: fritz config]

t

Comment: It seems you somehow mounted the share. How is FTP involved with that? // Just because you have write permissions does not mean the share (or any filesystem) is mounted read-write.

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand what you mean. Do you mean that the files themselves on the attached hard drive may not be writable by other users?

Comment: No. In Linux terms, I mean `mount -o ro`. Please describe how you are mounting the FritzBox file share.

Comment: Sorry i didn't get back to you. I am using a Mac and i press cmd + k to connect to a server, enter in the domain name and credentials, and once I'm in, I can read all the files but not write to them. I have Linux machines and Windows machines as well if needed.